# Как называется событие когда пользователь возвращается на вкладку?

Tags: javascript

Нужно обновить данные на странице когда пользователь на неё возвращается. То есть вкладка была не закрыта но пользователь с неё ушёл, а теперь вернулся.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте вот так:

`jQuery`:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    // Здесь что угодно после ухода в другую вкладку
});

$(window).focus(function() {
    // Здесь что угодно после возвращения во вкладку
});
```

Нативный `js`:

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   // Здесь что угодно после ухода в другую вкладку
});

window.addEventListener('focus',  function() {
   // Здесь что угодно после ухода в другую вкладку
});
```

Comment: не ошибаешься, только добавь ответ без jquery, так как нет этой метки.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас редактирую.

Answer (score 0):

visibilitychange

```js
window.addEventListener(
    'visibilitychange', 
    function() { 
        if (document.hidden === true) return;
        console.log('Вернулся');
    }, 
    false
);
```